# Trying to save data with Backendless: Internal client exception

Tags: java, backendless

I want to persist a `Employee` in my Backendless app:

```
Backendless.initApp(APP_CODE, REST_SECRET, version);

Employee e = new Employee(1, "Bonifacio Johnson");

Backendless.Persistence.save(e, new BackendlessCallback<Employee>(){

  @Override
  public void handleResponse(Employee employee) { //Do something }

  @Override
  public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) { //Do something }

});
```

**This code is not in Android app, but in Java server.**

I get this fault:

> BackendlessFault{ code: 'Internal client exception', message:
>   'api.backendless.com' }

Am I right using REST secret? How can I obtain more info about the error?

Comment: Please share full error output

Answer (score 0):

When you use Backendless Android SDK in plain Java you still need to set Android secret key.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I get the same error with the Android secret key.